# dll already loaded in another classloader in netbeans using tomcat

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, netbeans, classloader, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Currently I develop an java web application using spring mvc, netbeans as IDE, and tomcat as web server.

I want to use 3rd party jar and it seems no problem occurs when I use the jar in simple java application. But when i use it in my webapp, it triggers an error, this is the error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library C:\Program Files (x86)\SafeNet\Protect Toolkit C SDK\bin\jcprov.dll already loaded in another classloader
```

this the code that call classes in the jar:

```
    CryptokiEx.C_Initialize(new CK_C_INITIALIZE_ARGS(CKF.OS_LOCKING_OK));
//below code cause error
    CryptokiEx.C_OpenSession(0, CKF.RW_SESSION, null, null, session);
```

The second line of the code will cause the error.

The first time the code executed, it did not trigger the error, buat after that, it always trigger the error. I tried to stop tomcat from netbeans, close the netbeans and re-open again, and it still triggers the error.

I googled for answer and it points me to this link:

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#I.27m_encountering_classloader_problems_when_using_JNI_under_Tomcat

But it says that the class that load the native library should be placed in $CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib. I placed the jar to the directory but the error still occurs.

I then run this in command line: mvn tomcat:run on my project directory and the error did not occurs this time, I do not know why. But still, I want to run it from netbeans, not from command line.

I assume that even I have placed the jar in shared $CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib, my webapp still depends on the jar that placed in lib folder of my webapp project, not the jar that placed in $CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib. I use in-project repository to include the jar, but how to include the jar that placed in $CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib?

I really appreciate any help from you guys,
Thanks!

Comment: Have you found any solution ?   How about using <scope>provided</scope> in your maven dependency ?

Comment: are you using Tomcat 7 ?

Comment: I use Tomcat 7 and still not found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is even [a static-dll-bootstrapper project](http://code.google.com/p/static-dll-bootstrapper/) to do everything in a proper way.

Your trouble should be solved in a few simple steps.

- Place the jar to shared.loader path
- define lib name in `dll-bootstrapper.properties` near the jar
- place `Class.forName("msm.DLLBootstrapper");` in your project code
- enjoy